# Command equivalent to AntiForgery.Validate() in asp.net-core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, antiforgerytoken

Exists, in asp.net-core, a command similar to `AntiForgery.Validate();` to validate antiforgery token in the action body?

Code example in dotnet 4.5.1:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
    }

    // rest of action
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antiforgery token validation can be done automatically using filter attributes in your controllers.

- Use `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` to validate the token on all "unsafe" methods. (Methods other than GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS).
- Use `[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]` to always validate the token
- Use `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to ignore token validation

You can combine these attributes to achieve the granularity you need. For example:

```
//Validate all 'unsafe' actions except the ones with the ignore attribute
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public class MyApi: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DoSomething(){ }
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult DoSomethingElse(){ }

    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]   
    public IActionResult DoSomethingSafe(){ }
}

//Validate only explicit actions
public class ArticlesController: Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(){ }

    [ValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]   
    public IActionResult Create(){ }
}
```

I have noticed the documentation isnt fully ready in the [docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery), but you can see a draft of it in the github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/89#issuecomment-251278758).

Answer (score 4):

Based on Daniel`s answer, I change the code to

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return NewIndex();
    }

    // rest of action
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewIndex()
{
    // body of new action
}
```

Another option, based on [docs draft](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jfmncpp0z79m9mt/AACejY50rKGjSPpAnd5m2q_8a/Preventing%20XSRF%20in%20ASP.NET%20CORE.docx?dl=0), is inject `Antiforgery` as an service.

Project.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery": "1.0.0"
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    ...


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery();
    ...
```

Then validate on controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public AccountController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery; 
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext);
        }

        // rest of action
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The antiforgery token is automagically generated and added by `FormTagHelper`.
You can disable/enable this automatic feature by adding the `asp-antiforgery="true"` attribute:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" asp-antiforgery="true" 
      method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
</form>
```